# I want to listen to changes on the server and update my web page accordingly. How can I do this with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, server-side, long-polling

I am building a web page that pulls data from a server and displays it. The data can change and I want to be able to change the data on the webpage without refreshing the page and not use setInterval. How can I do this with Javascript? Can this be done with Backbone.js?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `setInterval()` exactly?

Comment: Backbone as client-side library can't listen to changes on the server, you should consider using Websocket or Comet.

Comment: Yes it may be done with backbone.js (and server support, of course). What doesn't work with that?

Answer (score 2):

you could use a setInterval that goes to the server and pulls new updates and update the DOM.

If you're using HTML5 then use web sockets which will actually have the server push the updates to the connected client.

If you're writing in .NET then I really really recommend checking out [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) which will make life easier.